# how to append zero's to array which is already having a binary values

Tags: c#

I have a decimal value of 126 which is converted to binary value using the below code:

```
binary[i] = Convert.ToString(bmparrayelement[i], 2);
```

then I got the value as "111 1110" which is right.

Then I want to append zeros along with this value in prefix that is "00 0111 1110"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var binary = new byte[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};
var zeroed = new byte[] {0, 0};
binary = zeroed.Concat(binary).ToArray();
```

**Update**
In .net 2.0 you can use:

```
        const int number = 2;
        var binary = new byte[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};

        var a = new byte[binary.Length + number];
        binary.CopyTo(a, number);
        binary = a;
```

Comment: i am using 2.0 framework,so i can change the type from var to string.here the number of zeroes to append is dynamic it can be 1 ,2 or it can be 10. In this case how can i do it.,

Comment: Could you write in details what do you need? In any cases adding elements to array through string is not good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:-

```
 string s1 = Convert.ToString(byteArray[20], 2).PadLeft(10, '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I have misunderstood but why can't you just do the below?

```
binary[i] = "00 0" + Convert.ToString(bmparrayelement[i], 2);
```